# All available verbs for explorer contextmenu

Tags: contextmenu, explorer

I was looking for all available verbs for `Windows Explorer's` `ContextMenu` for a `shortcut(.lnk)` file.

But I can't find any master list kind of thing on MSDN or anywhere else.

Where can I get these ?

Comment: Quite possibly the answer is "you can't find a precompiled list; it's built dynamically".

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for your response. I am looking for "Open File Location" verb .

Comment: I don't get it - first you asked about a list of verbs,  now you have a verb but don't tell us what you want to know about it.

Comment: @MSalters I am looking for the verb which corresponds to "Open File Location" menuitem which appears when you right click a shortcut. If there is a master list, then I could have gone through that list.